# Multiprocessing python working OK when expected to work bad

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, spyder

This is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from random import random

from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    for i in range(5):
        print("hola" , i)
        sleep(random())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=f)
    q = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    q.start()
    print("fin")
    ## sleep(1000)
```

and this is the output that i *always* get:

```
fin
('hola', 0)
('hola', 1)
('hola', 2)
('hola', 3)
('hola', 4)
('hola', 0)
('hola', 1)
('hola', 2)
('hola', 3)
('hola', 4)
```

but the code does not contain anything to prevent both processes from mixing, so why is it that they don't mix?

Windows 8, Python 2.7, using last version of spyder from anaconda

Comment: You start them one after another. That may be the reason.

Comment: @Creator  I really don't understand that comment sorry

Comment: I am not sure how Python works, but it may have to do with the fact that you call p.start and then q.start .

Comment: This isn't related to Windows. Spyder must set the process standard output to a pipe. Since `sys.stdout` isn't interactive (i.e. tty or console), Python uses buffered I/O. You're not writing enough data for the buffer to be flushed in either child process until each process exits. You can replicate this from the command-line using `python test.py | more`.

Comment: You can set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to force Python to use unbuffered standard I/O. Note however that this actually does cause a Windows-related problem in Python 2.x because it also switches `stdin` to binary mode instead of translating `\r\n` to `\n`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb and say it is Windows: Just ran your sample on Python 2.7.10 on Mac OS x Yosemite and I got a somewhat more expected result:

```
In [27]: def f():
   ....:         for i in range(5):
   ....:                 print("hola" , i)
   ....:                 sleep(random())
   ....:         

In [28]: if __name__ == "__main__":
   ....:         p = Process(target=f)
   ....:         q = Process(target=f)
   ....:         p.start()
   ....:         q.start()
   ....:         print("fin")
   ....:     
fin

In [29]: ('hola', 0)
('hola', 0)
('hola', 1)
('hola', 2)
('hola', 1)
('hola', 3)
('hola', 4)
('hola', 2)
('hola', 3)
('hola', 4)
```

See if this helps:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Thanks for trying the code, we use Ubuntu in classroom so i was already suspecting this, because i only have this "problem" with my laptop, but i need to be able to work from my laptop :(

Comment: Try extending the length of you random (multiply it by ten and see what happens.) Also you can try importing random inside of f and see what happens. whenever you have weird behavior like this it is very easy to experiment in Python and see what's going on.

Comment: Something i should have said before, the output is printed by blocks and not line by line. So with   random()*10   i get the same output (printed by blocks) but it just takes longer